# How to disable layered navigation on certain categories

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I want to disable the layered navigation on some certain categories, can someone help me?

case 1:

> disable it through category id, for example on category id 4

case 2:

> only disable it on parent categories. For example, if category A has
>   subcategories, disable it on category A. But it will be shown at
>   category A's subcategories

Comment: Take a look at category anchor attribute.

Comment: Thanks, If I set the anchor at the parent category to NO. It will case another problem: all products won't display under this category...

Answer (score 6):

Hi if you want to delete you layered navigatino category wis then you can use below:
Admin Menu:
catalog->cateogry

> 1.Select your category.
>
> 2.open custom design tab.
>
> 3.add following code in **Custom Layout Update**:
>
> ```
> <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
> ```
>
> 4.Save cateogry.

Comment: Very Good Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,can go this two ways.

1. Make this category non anchor from admin.

2.Using layout xml code

```
<CATEGORY_MYCATID>
  <reference name="left_first">
     <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
    </block>
  </reference>

</CATEGORY_MYCATID>
```

on Layout xml file  (catalog.xml or local.xml) add

```
<CATEGORY_78>
  <reference name="left_first">
     <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
    </block>
  </reference>
</CATEGORY_78>
```

78 category id

Comment: Hi, I don't understand <CATEGORY_MYCATID>  , how to use this handle? Thanks